# AJAX Rendering 400 Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

The goal is to load the comment for each article on my `index` page using AJAX.

I'm getting a `bad request` error 400:

```
ERROR bad URI `/comments/%3C%=%20comment.id%20%%3E?_=1457892605480'.
```

Index:

```
 #welcome/index.haml
    - @articles.each do |article|
       = article.title
       - article.comments.each do |comment|
         %comment-content{ :id => "comment-<%= comment.id %>", :class => "comment-content", "data-comment-id" => "<%= comment.id %>"}
```

JS:

```
    #comments.js
    var loadComment = function() {
    return $('.comment-content').each(function() {
    var comment_id = $(this).data('comment-id');
    return $.ajax({
      url: /comments/+comment_id,
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'script',
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        return console.log("AJAX Error: " + textStatus);
      },
      success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        return console.log("Worked OK!");
      }
    });
  });
};

$(document).ready(loadComment);

$(document).on('page:change', loadComment);
```

Show:

```
 #comments/show.js.erb
 $('#comment-<%= @comment.id %>').append('j render(@comment.content)');
```

Routes:

```
resources :articles do
      resources :comments do
      end
end
```

Comment: your url needs to be a string: url: "/comments/" + comment_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you URLdecode the URL in the error message, you'll get the following:

```
ERROR bad URI `/comments/<%= comment.id %>?_=1457892605480'.
```

Seeing that, the error becomes quite clear: the interpolations in your HAML template are wrong. Instead of ERB interpolation style, you need to use the ruby string interpolation style, as described in [HAML docs](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#ruby_interpolation_):

```
%comment-content{ :id => "comment-#{comment.id}", :class => "comment-content", "data-comment-id" => comment.id }
```

Comment: Thanks. Now, Im getting a routing error `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/comments/2"):`. The correct route is `articles/1/comments/2` which I have no idea how to fix but I guess that's for a different question.

Answer (score 1):

your url needs to be a string:

```
url: "/comments/" + comment_id
```